# How to attach() and detach() instead of add() and remove() to save fragment view

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, savestate

I have the following code for `ActionBar`:

```
private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mFrag;

    public MyTabListener( Activity activity, String fragName )
    {
        mActivity = activity;
        mFrag = fragName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
    {
        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate( mActivity, mFrag );
        ft.add( android.R.id.content, mFragment );
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
    {
        ft.remove( mFragment );
        mFragment = null;
    }
}
```

I have some textboxes within those `Tab` fragments and switching between the tabs forces the app to lose any data I added to those textbox. Instead of `add` and `remove`, I would like to use `attach` and `detach` which saves the fragment state.

How do I accomplish that within the code that I already have?

**Update**:

The code now looks like this:

```
private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mFrag;

    public MyTabListener( Activity activity, String fragName )
    {
        mActivity = activity;
        mFrag = fragName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
    {
        //mFragment = Fragment.instantiate( mActivity, mFrag );
        //ft.add( android.R.id.content, mFragment );
          mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mFrag);
          if( mFragment == null ) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mFrag);
          } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
    {
        //ft.remove( mFragment );
        //mFragment = null;
          if (mFragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mFragment); 
              }
    }
}
```

And I am getting an error for the following line:

```
mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mFrag);
```

Error:

```
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Activity
```

Comment: The solution I would give here is the exact same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634247/save-fragment-state-inside-a-tab. What's the difference?

Comment: I was just having a little trouble plugging in the variables between your code and my pre defined code :/

Comment: Did you get it working? I think the key component you're missing here is the tag when you do `ft.add(viewID,fragment,TAG)`

Comment: Can I leave my code as is and add the TAG? And what would TAG be?

Comment: In this case, the tag would be `mFrag`. When you initialize the TabListener, you send in `public MyTabListener( Activity activity, String fragName )` and set `mFrag = fragName`. You need to use this tag to retrieve the fragment.

Comment: I updated my question with the updated code but I am receiving an error. Can you please check? Thanks

Comment: Are you making sure to import the right libraries? the `supportFragmentManger` is from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: Yes, I just added the IMPORT statement but it's still not working.

Comment: check to see if your activity is extending `FragmentActivity`

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {` and also: `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;` If I change the line to: `mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mFrag);` it doesn't give an error.

Comment: IDK if the targetSDK has anything to do with it. I have the following:
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rewriting your code, you could just use `SharedPreferences` to temporarily store the variables being displayed.

In the `onDestroy` method of the tab you're leaving, just add your variables to the preferences, and retrieve them when you re-enter the tab.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("OnDestroy", "Logged");
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("stringName", stringToStore);
    editor.commit();
}
```